# Configure two different job repositories within one Spring application context. Is it right to do so?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a scenario where I have to run some jobs on application startup and some at some later point using exposed REST services end points. Is it possible to create two different job repositories in xml for the said two purposes within one single Spring application? Would that be right doing so? How can I achieve this using Spring xml beans?

Answer (score 1):

The `job` element has a `job-repository` attribute that allows you to define which job repository the job should report to. So you can create multiple job repositories and assign which one you want to each job:

```
<bean id="jobRepository1">...</bean>
<bean id="jobRepository2">...</bean>

<batch:job id="job1" job-repository="jobRepository1">...</batch:job>
<batch:job id="job2" job-repository="jobRepository2">...</batch:job>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, but how do we have a separate jobRegistry for 2 different jobRepositories?